# Recorder only records 9 seconds in android 12 using mediaRecorder

Tags: android, kotlin, mediarecorder

I have an application which records calls , it works fine so far and it does record the calls , the issue is about the duration that the mediaRecorder records which is roughly 9 seconds in android 12  , when i try on android 11 and downwards , it works pretty fine , i'm not sure why it does not record the whole call in android 12 , any reason why ?? Thank you for the help in advance .

- This is receiver where i start recording the call

```
 class PhoneCallReceiver  : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager
    var prevState: String = TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE
    private  var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    private lateinit var filePath : String

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        notificationManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val bundle = intent?.extras ?: return
        val state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

        if(state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE && prevState == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Call Ended",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            stopRecording(context)
            prevState = state!!
        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Phone Ringing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else if(state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK){
            startRecording(context)
            Toast.makeText(context,"Call Answered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun startRecording(context: Context){
        var recordingPath = "xxxxxxxx"
        showNotification(context = context,"Recording ...","Recording started ...")
        mediaRecorder = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
            MediaRecorder(context)
        } else {
            MediaRecorder()
        }

        val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/RecordingFolder")
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdir()
        }
        mediaRecorder!!.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC)

        val choice = Extras.getPrefs(context)
        
        mediaRecorder!!.setOutputFormat(choice)
        mediaRecorder!!.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
        mediaRecorder!!.setOutputFile(recordingPath)

        try {
            mediaRecorder!!.prepare()
            mediaRecorder!!.start()
        } catch (ex : Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG","Exception Caught")
        }

    }

    private fun stopRecording(context: Context){
        notificationManager.cancel(1)
        showNotification(context = context,"Recording Ended","Recording was successful")
        if(mediaRecorder != null){
            mediaRecorder!!.stop()
            mediaRecorder!!.release()
            mediaRecorder = null
        }
    }
    private fun showNotification(context: Context,contentTitle : String , contentText : String){

        val notificationCompat = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Extras.NOTIFICATION_ID)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_circle_notifications_24)
            .build()

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(1,notificationCompat)
    }
}
```

- Permissions which are granted

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This should not work on an Android 11 device too.

Comment: Is the directory created? Dont think so.

Comment: if (!file.exists()) if (!file.mkdirs()) return; Also display a toast to inform the user.

Comment: @blackapps Yes the directory is created and it does save the file , when i play file in android 11 and downwards , it shows and play the whole call with full duration , but in android 12 , it does save the file ( for example i make a call of 1:00 minutes ) , it gets saved when i play it , it is only 9 seconds ... what could be the issue , permissions , anything ??

Comment: Did you implement MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE by the way?

Comment: @blackapps i have shared the permissions that i grant while using the app which includes the Both read and write external storage .

Comment: On Android 11+ devices your app cannot create folders in root of external storage. So this is all hard to believe.

Comment: You are not using that directory. And `var recordingPath = "xxxxxxxx"` well we do not know what you do.